# Test cases for find and replace function of notepad

Tags: test-design

I have made a notepad in c and i want to add find & replace feature so i just want some test case for that feature so that it works fine in notepad editor.

Comment: I think 'FrustratedWithFormsDesign' answered this nicely over at programmers.stackexchange.com. http://bit.ly/oj1t8W

Comment: This question was asked and answered, as @Todd pointed out, on another site. The question does not appear to really have had a lot of research or effort added to it, more like someone is looking for help with an interview or test question, hence the down vote.

Comment: Downvoting for the reasons TristaanOgre mentioned.

Comment: I agree with Tristaan and User246; this question shows little effort

Comment: Welcome to SQA.se, rohit! I notice a distinct lack of a question here. There are a great number of different ways to test, and it would be much better if you could provide some more details: background of why you wrote it, what you hope your tests will accomplish, how comprehensive these tests are intended to be, and the like. If you edit this post, post a comment to let me know so I can reopen it, or feel free to post a new question that... actually has a question :-) One of the hallmarks of a good question is showing what research you've already done so others can pick up where you left off.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you do the following:

1. Start with a list of things the feature is supposed to do. You
   should already have this from when you created the feature. If you have a function specification, use that to create the list.
2. For each item on the list write some [test cases](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/search?q=test%20case) to test the item.
3. Edit your question and add the list of tests you created. Ask if your test cases are good or not.